Django populate Model form dynamically with model - possible?
I am trying to use a model form independently of the model that is passed.
My goal is to have a list of database tables where the user can select the table which is then displayed. Then within this table there is the possibility to select a table entry which can be updated. There will be changing tables over time, therefore I want to use one model form to include all the fields for editing and just change the underlying Model.
I tried some things and right now this is my "last" attempt that is not working. Any advice or guidance?
This is in my views.py
class DynamicModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = '__all__'

# setting the model based on the input selection of user
def get_dynamic_form(request, model, instance=None):
    DynamicModelForm.model = model
    DynamicModelForm.fields = '__all__'
    return DynamicModelForm(request.POST or None , instance=instance)
#
#
#
# in my class based view I am using this to list the tables
def list(self, request, model, model_name):
        print(f'Pulling model {model_name}')
        objects = model.objects.all()
        fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]  # Retrieve field names


        
        self.context['fields'] = fields
        self.context['model_name'] = model_name 
        self.context['objects'], self.context['info'] = set_pagination(request, objects)
        if not self.context['objects']:
            return False, self.context['info']

        return self.context, 'app/transactions/table_view.html'



This is what a modelform_factory does.

Your get_dynamic_form, is essentially what Django does with a modelform_factory(…) [Django-doc]. Indeed, we can thus work with:
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory


def get_dynamic_form(request, model, instance=None):
    return modelform_factory(model, fields='__all__')(
        request.POST or None, instance=instance
    )
